# Calculate direction from dx, dy?

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I have a vessle that is traveling in a direction:

```
class Vessle{
    constructor() {
        this.position = {
            x: this.rnd(bound.width),
            y: this.rnd(bound.height),
            dx: this.rnd(5),
            dy: this.rnd(5)
        }
    }
    rnd(val) {return val * Math.random()}
    move(){
        this.position.x += this.position.dx;
        this.position.y += this.position.dy;    
    }
}
```

When I draw it on a canvas I want to rotate the image so it's pointing in the traveling direction:

```
    drawImage(pos){
        let w = this.img.naturalWidth,
            h = this.img.naturalHeight
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(pos.x+w/2, pos.y+h/3);
        this.ctx.rotate(Math.atan(pos.dx,pos.dy));
        this.ctx.translate(-pos.x-w/2, -pos.y-h/3);
        this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, pos.x, pos.y);
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
```

This should be done in this line:

```
this.ctx.rotate(Math.atan(pos.dx,pos.dy));
```

They point in other directions in a to me inconsistent way(not like all of them pointing 90deg wrong etc)  I have the wrong units or something?

Comment: "It doesn't work" meaning it points in the wrong direction or it doesn't change orientation at all?

Comment: From what I understand of your code you're not performing your canvas update by batches. The rotate function actually alters the [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) of your canvas so each time you `.rotate()` you increment offset angle of your axis. You should somehow keep a reference of the offset angle and reDraw each time

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get an angle between to points (in degrees):

`var angleDeg = Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;`

If I'm correct, you are rotating "on top" of your previous rotation, so you should take that into account.